NAT type is strict
I've been having problems playing GTA Online for the past week. I have encountered long wait times (up to 30 minutes or even 2 hours) when trying to join GTA Online sessions. Even when I manage to enter a public session or lobby, I frequently get disconnected within 5-10 minutes and automatically end up in a solo session.
In summary, my issues include:

Long wait times
Frequent disconnections
Increased latency

The game reports my NAT is strict and I assume this is the main cause of the issues. I have followed all the instructions provided by Rockstar Games support regarding Network Address Translation (NAT). Despite my efforts, NAT type remains strict. The Rockstar support team advised me to contact my Internet Service Provider (ISP) to resolve this issue.
My ISP informed me that changing my NAT type from strict to open would require purchasing a static IP address. I am uncertain whether this advice is accurate, as I do not understand the correlation between a static IP address and NAT type.
Could you please confirm if purchasing a static IP address will indeed change my NAT type to open? I would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving this matter.

It has to be asked: Why do you assume this is an issue with your current game account? If you login to the old version of the game on your old account do you have similar problems or not? ISPs won't simply change the NAT to open on one of their customer's accounts because they ask, and it may not be that a Static IP is required for NAT to be open, but that the ISP has "tiers of service" and the open NAT service is an option/function of the Static IP option.

Are you subject to carrier-grade NAT? Go to your router’s website, check the “WAN IP address” (sometimes also “Public” or “External” or “Internet”) it shows. Does it start with 100.64.x.x though 100.127.x.x? Is it an obviously private IP address like 10.1.2.3? Is it different from the address that “what is my IP” type websites report?

So the answer to your question is to either do what your ISP tells you, or find a different ISP.
There is no actual technical requirement that Open NAT be associated with a static IP directly; the two concepts are independent of each other; but your ISP may have engineered its network to require one for reasons of their choosing, which may be motivated on a spectrum of considerations ranging from an understandable dearth of available IPs to sheer, unadulterated greed.
If your ISP says it must be this way, that's just the way it is. They are the ones in control.
One of the few options available is you can look into VPN or other tunneling services that may allow you to NAT (or directly connect) to the game network bidirectionally, but tunnels are likely to have some impact on latency (and thus game performance) and are likely charge a subscription fee. These kinds of services will bypass the ISPs control of the remote gateway your traffic passes outward through. Once again, that VPN service will have to support this kind of use.
or of course, you can look for an ISP that allows users to configure NAT without additional charges.
